# Why doesn't the Earth's magnetic field affect electronics?

Tags: electromagnetism, earth, estimation, electronics, geomagnetism

Why doesn't the Earth's magnetic field affect electronics in the same way that a magnetic field affects/exerts a force on a wire with a charge at a perpendicular angle? Isn't that why electric motors work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it does. The Earth's magnetic field is about half a gauss, or $0.5\times10^{-4}\rm\,T$.  So if you have a meter of wire carrying one ampere of current from east to west, it'll feel a magnetic force of $0.5\times10^{-4}\rm\,N$ in some mixture of upwards and the north-south direction that depends on the tilt of Earth's field at your location.  (I'm in the US Southeast and the field is about 70° from the horizontal, so if I did the experiment the force would be mostly to the north.)  That force corresponds to the weight $mg$ of an object with mass $m=5\rm\,mg$, which is pretty small compared to any real one-meter wire that wouldn't melt under an ampere of current.  Furthermore, most mains current is rapidly alternating, and most current carriers are *cables* which have both the supply and return currents right next to each other, which are both effects that make it harder to measure the force.

Earth's magnetic field can be a big annoyance if you're designing or using an instrument where free charges move and their exact trajectories matter, like a [photomultiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomultiplier) or a [cathode-ray tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube).

Comment: Generations of CRT televisions and video monitors were aligned (if one was careful) facing north-south before making fine adjustments.

Answer (score 3):

Earth's magnetic field is just too weak. half a gauss is nothing compared to your standard refridgerator magnet.

Comment: Thanks! It won't let me accept the answer. Too new on Physics stack exchange...

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the Earth's magnetic field does affect electronics, probably, in a positive way, as it protects it from the effects of cosmic rays.

Comment: But wouldn't a simple magnet provide protection from rays within its influence? Like if we were on the moon, could we just generate a field to do the same?

Comment: @oeste That is a different question that could be posted as such.

Comment: @oeste: A simple magnet can only act within a volume with a dimension of, say, 1 m. The Earth's magnetic field acts within a volume with a dimension of, say, $10^6$ m (comparable to the Earth's radius). Therefore, to deflect charged particles of the same momentum you need a "simple magnet" with a magnetic field that is $10^6$ stronger than the Earth's magnetic field, i.e., tens and hundreds of Tesla. This is impracticable for protection of electronics (as far as I know, the field of the strongest laboratory DC magnet is 45 Tesla).